# PhoneGap App Crashes while installing in my iPhone..

Tags: iphone, cordova, crash, ipa

I have created the app using Phonegap 2.7.0 version.I have build the .ipa file and installed it.App crashed, But using Phonegap 1.6.0 Version it's working well. No crashes on installation.Please help me. this is my config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--

-->
<widget>
    <preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="false" />
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="cloud" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="false" />
    <preference name="EnableLocation" value="false" /><!-- DEPRECATED -->
    <preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="false" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value=".25" />
    <preference name="HideKeyboardFormAccessoryBar" value="false" />
    <preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="true" />
    <preference name="KeyboardShrinksView" value="false" />
    <preference name="MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="true" />
    <preference name="SuppressesIncrementalRendering" value="false" />
    <preference name="TopActivityIndicator" value="gray" />

    <content src="index.html" />

    <plugins>
        <plugin name="Device" value="CDVDevice" />
        <plugin name="Logger" value="CDVLogger" />
        <plugin name="Compass" value="CDVLocation" />
        <plugin name="Accelerometer" value="CDVAccelerometer" />
        <plugin name="Camera" value="CDVCamera" />
        <plugin name="NetworkStatus" value="CDVConnection" />
        <plugin name="Contacts" value="CDVContacts" />
        <plugin name="Echo" value="CDVEcho" />
        <plugin name="File" value="CDVFile" />
        <plugin name="FileTransfer" value="CDVFileTransfer" />
        <plugin name="Geolocation" value="CDVLocation" />
        <plugin name="Notification" value="CDVNotification" />
        <plugin name="Media" value="CDVSound" />
        <plugin name="Capture" value="CDVCapture" />
        <plugin name="SplashScreen" value="CDVSplashScreen" />
        <plugin name="Battery" value="CDVBattery" />
        <plugin name="Globalization" value="CDVGlobalization" />
        <plugin name="InAppBrowser" value="CDVInAppBrowser" />
    </plugins>

    <access origin="*" />
</widget>
```

Comment: extract the crash log with iPhone Configuration Utility or iTunes and post it here

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide some code of your **config.xml** file.I have faced some similar problem.I forgot to write new version of the phonegap into the **config.xml** file and build using the new version and in config.xml file there is old version. so its make conflict for application and was crashed.
Note:

1. There are many upgradation are there for the phonegap 2.7.0 and sometimes however it will create issues if you use go straight with 2.7.0 from 1.6.0. 
   It may cause issues some times if you don't have any errors in your code.Hope this will help.

Ok.Good.
Put this into your widget tag and try to rebuild the application.

```
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="2.7.0" />
```